# Angular error: "Template parse errors: Parser Error: Missing expected : "

Tags: angular

I have this ngClass directive:

```
[ngClass]="{checkFav(fullArtist) ? 'action-btn-added' : 'action-btn-not-added'}"
```

Where checkFav is a function.
I get this error:

> Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 10 in [{checkFav(fullArtist) ? 'action-btn-added' : 'action-btn-not-added'}]

What am I doing wrong? I read a lot of answers, all of them suggesting things I already done like using quotes.

Comment: Wrong way around. {Classname: Condition}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change { to ( as

```
<div [ngClass]="(checkFav(fullArtist) ? 'action-btn-added' : 'action-btn-not-added')">Test</div>
```

But you should move logic to select class code to `checkFav(fullArtist)`

and only use `<div [ngClass]="checkFav(fullArtist)">Test</div>`

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rps3ma

Answer (score 1):

You need remove the curly braces. The aren't required for `ngClass` in this context. Try the following

```js
[ngClass]="(checkFav(fullArtist) ? 'action-btn-added' : 'action-btn-not-added')"
```